# ¿Por qué Sublime no está funcionando bien?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

una imagen vale más que mil palabras:

[image: Sublime Text dejó de funcionar]

Esto ocurre únicamente con el Sublime text 3, realicé una actualización hace unos días y desde entonces ocurre esto cada 30 minutos.

Aprovechado, alguien sabe de qué manera puedo generar la lista de nombres de mis plugins instalados?

Comment: probá bajandote alguna versión de Sublime Text 3 portable

Comment: Eso mismo estoy pensando ahora, pero para lo que estoy haciendo no creo que sea muy conveniente. Yo creo que fue la última actualización... Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes intentar eliminando las siguientes carpetas para dejar ST como si estuviese en una instalación limpia;

`OS X: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3`

`Windows: %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3`

`Linux: ~/.config/sublime-text-3`

Ten en cuenta que este procedimiento eliminará todas tus preferencias y paquetes(packages) que tengas instalado

Para eliminar la caché de sublime deberías eliminar las siguientes carpetas:

**En OS X**, la carpeta `~/Library`está oculta por defecto. Para acceder a ella, Selecciona en el menu del finder `Ir ▸ Ir a Carpeta` (Go ▸ Go to Folder), y escribe `~/Library`.

**En Windows**, los archivos de caché se almacenan en un lugar separado, %LOCALAPPDATA%\Sublime Text 3, para mejorar el rendimiento con los perfiles móviles..

Fuente: [Documentación de Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html)

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente si revisas los archivos de pluggins puedas ver cuales tienes instalados. Consulta este enlace, parece que podría funcionarte
[Configuracion Sublime Text 3](http://rootear.com/windows/como-instalar-plugins-sublime-text)